# Drawable resource with multiple color using layer-list in Android

Tags: android, android-drawable

I'm trying to make a drawable resource using layer-list which looks like this below.

[image]

is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Its possible,

### Code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><!--<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">-->
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:right="@dimen/_199sdp">
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="#FFFFFF" />
            <size
                android:width="@dimen/_1sdp"
                android:height="@dimen/_42sdp" />
            <!--                <corners android:radius="@dimen/_8sdp"/>-->
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item android:left="@dimen/_199sdp">
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="#FF0000" />
            <size
                android:width="@dimen/_1sdp"
                android:height="@dimen/_42sdp" />
            <!--                <corners android:radius="@dimen/_8sdp"/>-->
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item android:top="@dimen/_41sdp">
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="#673AB7" />
            <size
                android:width="@dimen/_200sdp"
                android:height="@dimen/_1sdp" />
            <!--                <corners android:radius="@dimen/_8sdp"/>-->
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item android:bottom="@dimen/_41sdp">
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="#CDDC39" />
            <size
                android:width="@dimen/_200sdp"
                android:height="@dimen/_1sdp" />
            <!--                <corners android:radius="@dimen/_8sdp"/>-->
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item android:left="@dimen/_1sdp" android:right="@dimen/_1sdp" android:top="@dimen/_1sdp" android:bottom="@dimen/_1sdp">
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="@color/trans" />
            <size
                android:width="@dimen/_200sdp"
                android:height="@dimen/_42sdp" />
            <!--                <corners android:radius="@dimen/_8sdp"/>-->
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

### Output

[image]